# Where is my Digital Ocean Droplet getting its files from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I've correctly set up and installed a Ruby on Rails application with Nginx on one of Digital Ocean's Ubuntu servers.

The default "DigitalOcean Rails Application" page was being displayed to me and told me that the file was located in `home/rails/rails_project/app/views/home/index.html.erb`

As a test I opened up the file with vim and changed a single line of plain text and it updated successfully.

Being a person with reasoning skills I then deleted the default `rails_project` directory and used `git clone` to substitute my own rails app. It worked, but the page didn't update. It still displayed the default page that I modified a single line on. Not the original page, the original page with a modified line that was in the directory I just deleted.

I tried opening the same file in vim and it just created a new one, so it didn't exist.

I then renamed the name of the directory I just cloned with git to `rails_project`, and then this happened:

Refreshing the page makes it toggle politely between the original default page and the one I modified (neither of which should exist) exactly 7 times before returning `500 server error` on the 8th and then beginning the whole thing again the next time you hit refresh.

This isn't some kind of anomaly and there's something basic I'm not doing right, but I'd appreciate it if somebody could explain to me what's happening and how to make the server recognize the application I added.

Test it yourself here by visiting this IP address: http://104.131.233.106/

Thanks. Sorry for the monotonous wall of text.

Comment: what happens when you do `ps aux | grep ruby` ?  is the old app still running?

Comment: root     21292  0.0  0.0  11740   936 pts/0    S+   18:08   0:00 grep --color=auto ruby (I'm not sure what I'm looking at, this is foreign territory to me)

Comment: doesn't look like a ruby process is running...

Comment: Right, I hadn't started the unicorn server. Now I'm being shown "We're sorry, something went wrong" :D, moving forward

Comment: Sounds like your server was serving a cached version of your app, it's not until you restart the server that the new version of the application will be picked up. As far as unicorns go, depending on how many unicorns you have running, it will require all of them to have the new version for it to no longer displayed. For example if you have 8 unicorns running, it's possible for some of them to serve the old version while the ones that have been restarted serve the new version. That is my guess of what I think happened in your case...